# Unable to send Post Request on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, http-post, postman, flutterwave

I am trying to send a post request to verify a transaction. I sent the same post request with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and I got a response as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Apps Script Code.gs:

```
function postRequest() {
    var url = "https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/verify";
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "payload": {
            "SECKEY": "FLWSECK-e6db11d1f8a6208de8cb2f94e293450e-X",
            "txref": "MC-1520443531487"
        }
    };

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Apps Script Error Response:

> Request failed for
>   https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/verify
>   returned code 400.
>
> Truncated server response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
>   
>    at parse
>   (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
>   
>    at /app/node_mod... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine
>   full response) (line 299, file "Code")

**What am I doing wrong or How do I send a post request in Google Apps Script?**

Comment: Send JSON instead of encoded form data. `payload = JSON.stringify(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function has an unusual quirk in that you have to use the `contentType` property to set the content type of the payload. For some reason, setting the header directly doesn't seem to work.

In addition you need to `JSON.stringify()` your payload.

So rewrite your post request as follows:

```
function verify() {
    var url = "https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/verify";

    var options = {
        "method":"POST",
        "contentType":"application/json",
        "payload":JSON.stringify({
            "SECKEY":"[YOUR-SECRET-KEY]",
            "txref":"[YOUR-TXREF-CODE]"
        })
    };

    return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
}
```

Note that I omitted the key and code with placeholder text. You really shouldn't share that kind of sensitive information. If possible I strongly recommend revoking those keys and have the service vendor issue new ones.

Comment: thanks,  it worked when I changed  `Content-Type` to  `contentType`

Comment: wow perfect ! I've been looking for this answer all day.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with Google Apps Script but the flutterwave server is returning a 400 error code.

You can check this by adding "muteHttpExceptions": true to the options object and then logging the response in the console.

```
function postRequest1() {
    var url = "https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/verify";
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "payload": {
            "SECKEY": "FLWSECK-e6db11d1f8a6208de8cb2f94e293450e-X",
            "txref": "MC-1520443531487"
        },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())
Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

Comment: thanks, but response code= 400.0 and response text= ' Unexpected token S<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)<br> .... '

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Dimu Designs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475731/6563022) for explaining a quirk of UrlFetchApp.fetch()

All I did to make it work was to change `Content-Type` to `contentType`

```
function postRequest() {
    var url = "https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/verify";
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "contentType": "application/json" // <--  HERE
        },
        "payload": {
            "SECKEY": "FLWSECK-e6db11d1f8a6208de8cb2f94e293450e-X",
            "txref": "MC-1520443531487"
        },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log('Response Code: '+response.getResponseCode())
}
```

On the other hand `"muteHttpExceptions": true` is there so that I will handle the Http exceptions myself.