# How to load search params to Leankit Post request from Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, postman

I have set up a working api call using Postman that returns the information that I want to return. I need to set up the same API call using google apps script but for some reason the search params are not loading. The api response gives the same result as the Postman response was without any search params being loaded.

My code so far is shown below. I've tried removing and adding back different settings in various orders but haven't found anything that finds the card related to the search term that I used.

```
function cardSearch(part) {
  var settings = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "Authorization": "Basic *********",
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Postman-Token": "************",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "contentLength": "60",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({"searchOptions": { "SearchTerm": part, "Page": 1 } })
// part is loaded into this function as a variable
  }
  var url = "https://**********.leankit.com/kanban/api/board/********/searchcards";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,settings);
  Logger.log(response);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var results = result.ReplyData[0].Results;
  Logger.log(results);
}
```

Expected Result:
JSON describing 1 or more cards titled or header'd with the search term of my choosing if one exists.

Actual Result: 
JSON describing the first 20 cards that were uploaded to the leankit board I'm referencing.

```
{TypeName=Test, ClassOfServiceId=0, Size=1, BlockReason=null, IsOlderThanXDays=true, SystemType=Card, Index=139, ActualStartDate=9/12/2018 4:11:09 PM, DrillThroughStatistics=null, CreateDate=9/10/2018, PriorityText=High, StartDate=9/12/2018, CurrentTaskBoardId=*****, ExternalCardIdPrefix=null, LastComment=null, AssignedUserIds=[******], CardTypeIconColor=212121, Version=84, LaneTitle=Finished As Planned, DrillThroughBoardId=null, Tags=Testing, SmallGravatarLink=********, ClassOfServiceCustomIconName=null, TypeId=*******, ClassOfServiceIconPath=null, DrillThroughProgressSizeComplete=null, ParentBoardId=0, Priority=2, Color=#0084FF, CurrentContext=Tasks, ExternalCardID=Material Testing, AssignedUsers=[{AssignedUserId=*********, AssignedUserName=*********, FullName=******** *****, Id=********, EmailAddress=******@*****.com, GravatarLink=*********, SmallGravatarLink=**********}], GravatarLink=********, DrillThroughProgressComplete=null, HasDrillThroughBoard=false, Active=false, ExternalSystemName=null, ExternalSystemUrl=null, Icon=, Id=********, DrillThroughCompletionPercent=null, CountOfOldCards=0, Description=<p>***********</p>, AssignedUserId=*******, ClassOfServiceTitle=null, LastAttachment=null, BoardId=**********, TypeColorHex=#0084FF, ActualFinishDate=9/15/2018 8:28:55 PM, HasMultipleDrillThroughBoards=false, CardDrillThroughBoardIds=[], TypeIconPath=null, ClassOfServiceColorHex=null, BoardTitle=********, TaskBoardTotalCards=3, DueDate=09/19/2018, DrillThroughProgressSizeTotal=null, IsBlocked=false, ParentCardId=null, ParentCardIds=[], AssignedUserName=******, TaskBoardCompletedCardSize=11, Title=Test Card, ClassOfServiceCustomIconColor=null, ParentBoardIds=[], CardTypeIconName=blank_icon, LastActivity=09/18/2018 03:28:55 PM, AttachmentsCount=0, DrillThroughProgressTotal=null, TaskBoardCompletionPercent=100, TaskBoardTotalSize=11, Type={Id=********}, CommentsCount=0, DateArchived=01/15/2018, LaneId=********, ParentTaskboardId=null, LastMove=09/16/2018 04:18:34 PM, TaskBoardCompletedCardCount=3, BlockStateChangeDate=null}
```

Comment: Will the problem be resolved if you put both the keys and values of the JSON request in quotes, as specified in the documentation?   E.g. `'method' : 'post'` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

Comment: I've posted the solution in the original post for anyone interested in solving this problem specifically. Thank @ziganotschka for their help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to put both the keys and values of the JSON request in quotes, as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object).)   E.g. `'method':'post'`
2. Everything that is not a valid parameter for `options` for `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` goes into `headers` or `payload`  - depending on the required syntax of the API you are calling. In particular:  `async` and `crossDomain` belongs into `headers`, while everything inside `data` should be assigned to `payload`
3. The [documentation for the request](https://success.planview.com/Planview_LeanKit/API/Application_API_-_v1/Application_API_(v1)%3A_Search_Cards) you are using specifies that the page number should not be in quotes

Those questions might be helpful for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35155175/11599789

[Unable to send Post Request on Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475286/unable-to-send-post-request-on-google-apps-script)

Comment: Ok, after numerous attempts, I still can't figure this out. Stringify(ing) the payload has not helped and I'm not sure where to go next. I updated the code to match what I'm currently using.

Comment: You still did not put  `async: true,    crossDomain: true,` inside of `headers`, and you don't use quotes

Comment: Oh you're right, I updated that however and am still running into the same issue

Comment: Also, may I ask you for references for your request syntax, i.e. the contents of data? And I don't think you need to JSON.stringify the payload

Comment: Try: "payload": {
        "searchOptions": {
          "SearchTerm": "part", "Page": 1 }
      }
Assuming that "part" is your search term and not the variable, in any case 1 goes without quotes

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the JSON that I'm expecting the api to return. I tried that and it gave me an error similar (I think) to the error that EdgeDev ran into in the post you linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198500/discussion-between-ziganotschka-and-jonathan-davis).